# Array Traversal to Get Sum of Each Path Respectively

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree

I got an 2-D array ([i][j]) where i levels of array with certain j elements each. Each element contains a number.

I drew somethings like this. Sorry for my drawing.
[image]

I found that there is a diagram called N-ary tree but the above seems different. May I know how to call the above diagram?

How to print the sum of each path using C#?
My idea is somethings like this:

```
    i=0, j=0
    +i=1, j=0
    +i=2, j=0
    +i=3, j=0
    +i=3, j=1
    +i=3, j=2
    +i=3, j=3

    i=0, j=0
    +i=1, j=0
    +i=2, j=1
    +i=3, j=0
    +i=3, j=1
    +i=3, j=2
    +i=3, j=3

    i=0, j=0
    +i=1, j=0
    +i=2, j=2
    +i=3, j=0
    +i=3, j=1
    +i=3, j=2
    +i=3, j=3

    i=0, j=0
    +i=1, j=0
    +i=2, j=3
    +i=3, j=0
    +i=3, j=1
    +i=3, j=2
    +i=3, j=3

    i=0, j=0
    +i=1, j=0
    +i=2, j=4
    +i=3, j=0
    +i=3, j=1
    +i=3, j=2
    +i=3, j=3

    i=0, j=0
    +i=1, j=1
    +i=2, j=0
    +i=3, j=0
    +i=3, j=1
    +i=3, j=2
    +i=3, j=3

    i=0, j=0
    +i=1, j=1
    +i=2, j=1
    +i=3, j=0
    +i=3, j=1
    +i=3, j=2
    +i=3, j=3

    i=0, j=0
    +i=1, j=1
    +i=2, j=2
    +i=3, j=0
    +i=3, j=1
    +i=3, j=2
    +i=3, j=3

    i=0, j=0
    +i=1, j=1
    +i=2, j=3
    +i=3, j=0
    +i=3, j=1
    +i=3, j=2
    +i=3, j=3

    i=0, j=0
    +i=1, j=1
    +i=2, j=4
    +i=3, j=0
    +i=3, j=1
    +i=3, j=2
    +i=3, j=3

         .
         .
         .
```

Comment: So you want all the paths from (0,0) to (n-1,m-1) where the array is nxm and a path allows you to move one row or one column at a time?  If so you're diagram is very confusing.

Comment: So looking closely at the "paths" I'm seeing stuff like i=1, j=0 followed by i=2, j=4.  First that actually sounds like you're dealing with a jagged array and not a 2D if the size of j can vary.  Second that makes me think you want to pick one number from each sub array as part of the "path".  Is that correct?  But then stuff like i=3, j=1 followed by i=3, j=2 doesn't make sense.  You really need to explain better the data you're dealing with and what constitutes a "path".

Comment: `how to call the above diagram` - Seems to be a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) - DAG for short, except yours doesn't show the (only) legal directions to move in.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It seems a bit different. My graph is all nodes in the first layer share all children in the second layer. And then all children in the Second layer share all children in the Third layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple method of creating the graph.  I assumed you can move in either direction on each path (not just down) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<Node>> nodes = new List<List<Node>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                int j = 0;
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0 :
                        j = 5;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        j = 7;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        j = 6;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        j = 4;
                        break;
                }
                List<Node> row = new List<Node>();
                nodes.Add(row);
                for (int col = 0; col < j; col++)
                {
                    Node newNode = new Node();
                    newNode.i = i;
                    newNode.j = j;
                    row.Add(newNode);
                }
            }
            //add neighbors
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count() - 1; i++)  // do not need to add neighbors to last row
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < nodes[i].Count(); j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < nodes[i + 1].Count(); k++)
                    {
                        Node currentNode = nodes[i][j];
                        Node neighbor = nodes[i + 1][k];
                        currentNode.neighbors.Add(neighbor);
                        neighbor.neighbors.Add(currentNode);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class Node
    {
        public int i { get; set; }
        public int j { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
        public List<Node> neighbors = new List<Node>(); 
    }

}
```